# Why can I not make an en passant capture?

Tags: rules, en-passant, captures

Here is part of a Lichess [game](http://ru.lichess.org/FLfYEpKd) where I tried make to make an en passant capture-but it's impossible. **The question is this-Why?** I am new to chess. I searched for the chess of rules on Wikipedia, but there was nothing specific about this case.

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 a6 2.d4 d6 3.Nf3 g6 4.Nc3 Bg7 5.Bd3 Nc6 6.Be3 Na5 7.O-O h6 8.Re1 Bf6 9.Qe2
b5 10.Rad1 b4 11.Nd5 Nc6 12.e5 Bxe5 13.dxe5 Bb7 14.e6 f5 *
```

Comment: The pawn on the 6th rank cannot take en passant.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to capture the pawn had he moved one square instead of two. Therefore you cannot take en passant (literally "while passing" in French)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess#En_passant) (is this what you read?)

> When a pawn advances two squares from its starting position **and there is an opponent's pawn on an adjacent file next to its destination square**, then the opponent's pawn can capture it en passant (in passing), and move to the square the pawn passed over. However, this can only be done on the very next move, otherwise the right to do so is forfeit. For example, if the black pawn has just advanced two squares from g7 (initial starting position) to g5, then the white pawn on f5 may take it via en passant on g6 (but only on white's next move).

The opponent moved 14...f7-f5. There is no White pawn on e5 or g5.

Answer (score 5):

If your e pawn was still on e5 then ef en passant would be a legal move but you cannot take en passant from e6.

The idea behind the en passant move is that originally pawns could only move one square at a time even on the first move. Then, with the white pawn on e5 black would have to first move f6 when white could capture the pawn normally. Then, in order to speed up the game, the rules were changed to allow a pawn to move 2 squares on the first move. The trouble with this was that it was unfair on the e5 pawn in the situation where black moves f7-f5. White has lost the chance to take e5xf6 because the f pawn has gone straight to f5. To fix this unfairness the en passant (in passing) rule was introduced to allow white to take the f pawn as if it had only moved one square. Because black could have moved f6-f5 next move this en passant possibility only lasts for one move.

As you can see, with your pawn already on e6 if black had played f7-f6 you would not be able to take. Therefore you also cannot take with your pawn already on e6 if he plays f7-f5.